# Debug .NET Core 3.1 Lambda Locally with Visual Studio

Tags: .net-core, aws-lambda

How do we debug a .NETCore 3.0/3/1 Lambda (Assuming I have an SQS or an S3 event processor) locally.  The .NET Core 2.1 version has a mock tool. How do we debug the .NET Core 3.0 with a mock tool?. This is till the AWS visual studio tools support .NETCore 3.1 .